# ListLogPlot with Legends inside the plot frame

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm trying to do ListLogPlot for the two lists of points

```
data1 ={{100,7.10934*^-11},{600,1.24888*^-10},{1100,1.29967*^-10},{1600,1.27995*^-10},{2100,1.2981*^-10},{2600,1.28602*^-10},{3100,1.29418*^-10},{3600,1.28796*^-10},{4100,1.29849*^-10},{4600,1.30531*^-10},{5100,1.29887*^-10},{5600,1.29934*^-10},{6100,1.29995*^-10},{6600,1.29672*^-10},{7100,1.30384*^-10},{7600,1.30762*^-10},{8100,1.29467*^-10},{8600,1.31142*^-10},{9100,1.29211*^-10},{9600,1.31159*^-10},{10100,1.30197*^-10},{10600,1.30517*^-10},{11100,1.31164*^-10},{11600,1.30673*^-10},{12100,1.30693*^-10},{12600,1.30377*^-10},{13100,1.30544*^-10},{13600,1.307*^-10},{14100,1.30303*^-10},{14600,1.30998*^-10},{15100,1.30301*^-10}}

data2 = {{100,1.98064*^-13},{600,2.17826*^-13},{1100,4.43912*^-12},{1600,5.40457*^-13},{2100,1.00364*^-13},{2600,2.30926*^-14},{3100,5.70433*^-13},{3600,3.41061*^-13},{4100,4.24549*^-13},{4600,1.24345*^-14},{5100,5.46674*^-13},{5600,8.08242*^-14},{6100,9.32587*^-14},{6600,6.32827*^-14},{7100,4.22062*^-12},{7600,9.10383*^-15},{8100,1.83944},{8600,1.45008},{9100,2.62997},{9600,0.672708},{10100,1.3049},{10600,1.48962},{11100,2.52422},{11600,15.8863},{12100,21.6495},{12600,5.45485},{13100,0.156453},{13600,9.29483},{14100,2.28007},{14600,8.27705},{15100,7.95017}}
```

using the following instructions in order to place the plot legends inside the frame:

```
ErAnl2 = ListLogPlot[{data1,data2},Joined->True, PlotLegends->Placed[LineLegend[{"Gauss-Gram","Direct"},LegendFunction->"Frame",LegendMarkerSize->0.1],{Right,Bottom}], Frame->True, FrameStyle->Thick, FrameLabel->{"c",Error}, LabelStyle-> Bold]
```

I got the following output 
[image]

where the legend box is placed badly.

Then I wanted to save the image by typing

```
CloudExport[ErAnl2,"PNG","ErAnl2", ImageResolution ->500]
```

but  I also got this strange one 
[image]

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: The `LegendMarkerSize -> 0.1` should be replaced with the default (remove option or use `LegendMarkerSize -> Automatic`)

Comment: If I remove it or use Automatic, I get the same picture

Comment: Edit your question to add the operating system and the version of Mathematica that you are using. Using the default, I cannot reproduce your problem with v12 on macOS 10.14.6

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there has been no feedback from the OP for an extended period of time. It works on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 with the suggestion above `LegendMarkerSize -> Automatic`.